# How can I divide a number of cells by another?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to do a query which divides a number of cells by another number of cells, but I keep on getting an error.

Here are the contents of those cells:
http://i.gyazo.com/5954cf9dfcdc8cc430b81125d7313d22.png

=SUM((Z2:Z19) / (V2:V19))

I get the #VALUE! error. How come I can't divide one selection by the other

Answer (score 2):

try this:

=(SUM(Z2:Z19)/SUM(V2:V19))

Comment: That worked great thanks! I tried something similar but it didn't work.

Comment: =SUM((Z2:Z19)/SUM(V2:V19))

Comment: you are welcome. You just have to pay attention to the placement of the brackets.

Comment: Will do so in future! Thanks again.